# The StackEgg tag

Tags: discussion, status-completed, policy

As many of you know by now, Stack Exchange added a minigame that looks like an advertisement at first glance to the right hand panel of all Stack Exchange sites. The game is called StackEgg and it's intended to simulate the evolution of a site in the SE network. It will only last through April Fool's Day, 2015 (i.e. 2015-04-01).

The game, though seemingly innocuous, has [gotten out of hand](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/252393/when-something-that-was-supposed-to-be-fun-became-not-fun). As a result, quite a bit of hostility has been directed toward PPCG in particular due to perceived cheating. (I know too little to comment in that regard.) Indeed, at least one PPCG user has been suspended from chat over it.

We have a tag now, [stack-egg](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/stack-egg) and I don't know where it came from. I filled out the description so that people know what it is when they see it, but my hope is that once the game is over, we can retire or remove the tag.

As of this writing there are only two PPCG posts bearing the tag and both have been put on hold and have a negative net vote count. However, after April Fool's Day, nothing related to StackEgg will be *relevant* or even *reproducible*.

So...

**Proposition: We delete the tag after 2015-04-02 or at least add a note to the tag wiki.**

Proposed note: "This tag is kept around for historical reasons. Questions of this type are not considered a good fit for this site, so rethink your challenge if you wanted to use this tag." (Same that was used for [code-trolling](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/code-trolling).)

Or do we already have a policy that would dictate our actions here?

Comment: As an aside, the purpose of a tag wiki is to clarify which questions belong in that tag. I voted to reject your suggestion as against the guideline ["Concentrate on what a tag means to *your* community"](http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2011/03/redesigned-tags-page/).

Comment: @PeterTaylor: Point taken. In this case now moot, since the tag has been deleted, but I'll keep that in mind the next time I'm thinking about editing a tag wiki. I appreciate you pointing that out and sharing the link.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Both questions tagged with the tag are closed, and unlikely to be reopened.

Since there is not currently a demand for the tag, I have removed it entirely. The zombie tag cleanup script should burninate it within the next 24 hours.

Comment: Thanks, @Doorknob! You're awesome!